# DotCMS Connecting to the database

Tags: sql-server, dotcms

I downloaded dotcms_2.3.2.zip
I have followed this documentation http://dotcms.com/docs/latest/InstallingFromRelease
I changed the url, username and password in `ROOT.xml`
MSSQL

```
    <Resource name="jdbc/dotCMSPool" auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
          url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://servername:portnumber/databasename"
          username="{xxxxx}" password="{xxxxx}" maxActive="60" maxIdle="10" maxWait="60000"
          removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="60" logAbandoned="true" 
          testOnBorrow="true" validationQuery="SELECT 1" defaultTransactionIsolation="READ_COMMITTED"/>     
</Context>
```

And in server.xml i changed `port to 8080`

```
<Connector maxThreads="75" connectionTimeout="3000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

And the main problem is I cant connect the ms sql database to dotCMS because when I go to `localhost:8080/admin/` link does work.
Any help?

Comment: What do you see when you ping your localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe,

username="{xxxxx}" password="{xxxxx}"

should look like

username="xxxxx" password="xxxxx"

(without curly braces).